# Silverlight zindex with dynamically added controls

Tags: silverlight, layout, grid, z-index

I have grid with some textboxes and an image which goes out of grid boundaries and I add this grids dynamically in my code to another grid.

I want to have my image on top of all the rest of the grids. Unfortunately each grid I add to the root grid will hover over my previous grid image.

Could you please suggest anything?! I have tried with zindex and it did not work in my case.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZIndex only works for the immediate children of a panel-derived container (Grid, Canvas, Stackpanel etc). Otherwise it is down to the order they exist in the visual tree (i.e. the last one gets displayed on top).

If you have nested objects you simply need to think about the order they are added. The simplest way to do this is have two top level grids/panels, the first contains *everything else* and the last containing just the dynamically added children.

This way whatever you put in the second grid will always be on top of all other items (in the first grid/container).